# Find the second largest value with Groupings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

In SQL Server, I am attempting to pull the second latest `NOTE_ENTRY_DT_TIME` (items highlighted in screenshot). With the query written below it still pulls the latest date (I believe it's because of the grouping but the grouping is required to join later). What is the best method to achieve this?

```
SELECT 
    hop.ACCOUNT_ID,
    MAX(hop.NOTE_ENTRY_DT_TIME) AS latest_noteid
FROM
    NOTES hop
WHERE 
    hop.GEN_YN IS NULL
    AND hop.NOTE_ENTRY_DT_TIME < (SELECT MAX(hope.NOTE_ENTRY_DT_TIME)
                                  FROM NOTES hope
                                  WHERE hop.GEN_YN IS NULL)
GROUP BY
    hop.ACCOUNT_ID
```

Data sample in the table:

[image: I would need the items highlighted]

Answer (score 3):

One of the "easier" ways to get the Nth row in a group is to use a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Account_ID,
           Note_Entry_Dt_Time,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY Note_Entry_Dt_Time DESC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT Account_ID,
       Note_Entry_Dt_Time
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 2;
```

Of course, if an `ACCOUNT_ID` only has 1 row, then it will not be returned in the result set.

The OP's statement *"The row will not always be 2."* from the comments conflicts with their statement *"I am attempting to pull the second latest `NOTE_ENTRY_DT_TIME`"* in the question. At a best guess, this means that the OP has rows with the same date, that could be the "latest" date. If so, then would simply need to replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `DENSE_RANK`. Their sampple data, however, doesn't suggest this is the case.

Comment: *"I am attempting to pull the second latest"* vs *"The row will not always be 2."* These statements, both from you @Chimbot , conflict. Which is it? it's either the second row, as it's the second latest, or it's not the second latest and not the second row.

Comment: Unless you can have multiple rows with the same date, but your (small) sample set doesn't suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        n.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by account_id order by note_entry_dt_time desc) rn
    from notes n
) t
where rn = 2
```